# How to run code after getting success true in http request in deferred.resolve after refreshToken

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am making a social platform in which user authentication is done by using oauth2.0 token system and when the accessToken get expired, i request for a refreshToken using Angularjs `OAuth.getRefreshToken();`
and after that somehow i requested again that last `401 http request` using `deferred.resolve($http(rejection.config));` but the problem now i am facing is that i had run a script in success true of previous api which is not running as both request are sending from different places. Here is my code. Hope you guys understood what i am saying.

app.js

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$window', 'OAuth', '$cookies', '$timeout','$q', '$http', function($rootScope, $window, OAuth, $cookies, $timeout, $q, $http) {
  $rootScope.$on('oauth:error', function(event, rejection) {

  // Ignore `invalid_grant` error - should be catched on `LoginController`.
  if ('invalid_token' === rejection.data.error || 'invalid_grant' === rejection.data.error || 'invalid_request' === rejection.data.error || 'invalid_client' === rejection.data.error || 'unauthorized_client' === rejection.data.error || 'unsupported_grant_type' === rejection.data.error) {
        $cookies.remove('userId');
        $timeout(function(){
            window.location.href = 'index.php';
        },200);
  }

  // Refresh token when a `invalid_token` error occurs.
  if ('expired_token' === rejection.data.error) {
      console.log(rejection);
      /*var $injector = angular.injector();
      var $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');*/
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var scope = $rootScope;
      OAuth.getRefreshToken();
      //console.log(refreshtoken.$$state);
      //console.log(rejection.config.headers.Authorization);
      //var state = true;
        /*setInterval(function() {
            var accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
            if(refreshToken && state==true){
                //rejection.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
                //console.log(accessToken);
                //console.log(rejection.config.headers.Authorization);
                //console.log(rejection.config);
                //deferred.resolve($http(rejection.config));
                //$window.location.reload();
                console.log(accessToken);
                console.log(refreshToken);
                state = false;
            }
        }, 5000);*/
  }

  console.log(rejection);
  console.log(rejection.data.error);
  console.log(rejection.data.error_description);

  // Redirect to `/login` with the `error_reason`.
  //return $window.location.href = 'index.php';

});
}]);
```

controller.js

This is for Login from which i get access token.

```
OAuth.getAccessToken($scope.user).then( function successCallBack(response){
            $scope.response = response;
            if($scope.response.status == 200){
                console.log($scope.response.data);
                $scope.accessToken      = $scope.response.data.access_token;
                $scope.refreshToken     = $scope.response.data.refresh_token;

                localStorage.setItem("accessToken", $scope.accessToken);
                localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", $scope.refreshToken);

                var userId = response.headers('userid');
                console.log(userId);
                $cookies.put("userId", userId);
                window.location.href = 'user_profile.php';
            }
        }, function errorCallBack(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
```

I searched lot how google or facebook does this but unable to understand how to run code which i have inserted in success true after repeating last http request.

```
var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('userId', $scope.userId);
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'xxxxxx/web/Users/public/removeFromBookmarks',
            data:fd,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.accessToken}
        }).then( function successCallBack(response){
            $scope.response = response;
            $scope.status = $scope.response.data.status;
            console.log($scope.status);
            if($scope.status == true){
                $scope.bookmarked = !$scope.bookmarked;
            }

        }, function errorCallBack(response){
            $scope.status = status;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
```

I want to run code which is `$scope.bookmarked = !$scope.bookmarked;` and the very first time if the token isnt expired then it easily run but when the same request is repeat by `deferred.resolve($http(rejection.config));` in app.js then the same code doesnt run.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So is this about Facebook login, or are you implementing your own OAuth system?

Comment: I am using angularjs [plugin](https://github.com/seegno/angular-oauth2)

Comment: So nothing to do with Facebook at all? Then please don’t tag it as a Facebook question. (Tag removed.)

Comment: I also want to know how facebook does this thing so i also implement.